# Looping through an array via iterator in C++

Tags: c++

Supposed I have a graph defined in such way,

```
unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> graph = {
    { 0, { 1, 2, 3 } },
    { 1, { 3, 4, 5 } },
    { 2, { 6, 5, 4 } }
};
```

And I want to empty the hash set of each entry in graph. I do two options here,

```
A. for(auto v = graph.begin(); v != graph.end(); ++v) v->second.clear();

B. for(auto v : graph) v.second.clear();
```

I see A works but B does not. I do not quite understand. My theory is, the way B is doing, v is a copy of the actual element. So it cannot clear the actual hash set.

Need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My theory is, the way B is doing, v is a copy of the actual element

Your theory is correct.

Since you want to modify the original, iterate with a reference instead of a copy:

```
for(auto& v : graph) v.second.clear();
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! And I have another question. According to my test, the running time of for(auto &v : graph) is longer than for(auto v : graph). I am confused here. The first way does not require making a copy of graph, v is just a reference. It will make more sense to me that the second one runs longer.

Comment: I see probably the longer time is due to the server is busier at the moment.

Comment: @CodingForFun15 Perhaps the compiler can deduce that clearing the temporary copies has no effect on the program, so it decides to remove the loop entirely.

Comment: @ user2079303 Make sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are working exclusively on a Windows Platform and have VS2012 or newer this method is also available to use.

```
typedef unordered_map<int, unordered_set<int>> Graph;

Graph myGraph = {
    { 0, { 1, 2, 3 } },
    { 1, { 3, 4, 5 } },
    { 2, { 6, 5, 4 } }
};

for each ( Graph& graph in myGraph ) {
    // Do Work Here!
    graph.second.clear();
}
```